# Cannot enter text into input field (Python + Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following snippet of HTML code on a web page:

```
<div class="f0n8F ">
    <label for="f395fbf9cde026" class="_9nyy2">Phone number, username, or email</label>
    <input class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" id="f395fbf9cde026" aria-describedby="slfErrorAlert" aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

And I am trying to input text using the following code:

```
username_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "f395fbf9cde026")))
username_element.send_keys('abc')
```

I keep getting a TimeOut exception, even when I try `(By.CLASS, "class _2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP")`, `(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"f1798b97d45a38\"]")`.

If I try `By.NAME, "username"`, there is another element with the name 'username' on the previous page, and so 'abc' is entered on this previous page before the above lines of code are executed.

Notably, if I ever try `driver.implicitly_wait(x)`, no wait ever occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to send *character sequence* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-describedby='slfErrorAlert'][name='username']"))).send_keys("KOB")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-describedby='slfErrorAlert' and @name='username']"))).send_keys("KOB")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you for the explanation. Following from this, I know nothing about frontend and HTML - how did you come up with this xpath from the snippet I sent? What is the format for xpaths?

Comment: @KOB This is most shortest [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) tutorial to start with.

Comment: Of course I will, can't do it for another couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try use the `xpath` which should be unique.

```
username_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username'][@aria-describedby='slfErrorAlert']")))
username_element.send_keys('abc')
```

Comment: See the last section of my question. This works, but the previous page before this one is opened also has an element with the name 'username', and the text is entered here before the new page is opened.

Comment: @KOB: can you try that.